# Xcode - Submission error - Unable to create configuration directory

Tags: configuration, directory, submit, writable

I was trying to submit my second app update and it failed submission after passing validation. This is the error:

"Unable to create configuration directory:/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/iTMSTransportation.woa/.itmstransporter. Cannot save local copy of remote diagnostic configuration;local path is not writable".

My screen shot of the error cannot be attached. I know it is not a network error at Apple's end because it specified a path in the Application Loader in Xcode. Since the system has read and write permissions here, it cannot be because I changed something. I submitted another app successfully earlier on the same day without a problem (as usual). I am at my wits’ end. Anyone experienced this?

Since there is no “Build for Archiving” in Xcode 5 (like in Xcode), I started with following steps:
1 - From the Xcode Product menu I selected “Archive” item
2 - After the Build, the organizer window appeared in the foreground with my archive in it.
3 -  I clicked the “Validate…” button and it executed that  successfully.
4 - When I clicked the “Distribute…” button, it started uploading the app but failed and came back with the aforementioned error. I went to the folder to see if any folder in the directory path is locked and also to see who has read and write permissions. It is not me but the system. I did a Disk Permission Repair in Disk Utility but that didn't help.

I then removed the offending file “.itmstransporter.” and tried to submit but got a different error. I put it back and took out the other two (ITMSTransporter.cmd and WOBootstrap.jar” but produced a different error. So I restored the folder to its original contents and returned to where I started - stymied. I have considered installing a new version of Xcode 5.0 but I don't know if that will help.
My OS:Mountain Lion 10.8.5, Xcode 5.0, MacBook Retina (first retina in 2012). Project compiled for iOS 7 in the Build Settings.
Thanks for any pointers.

￼

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I copied the whole "Application Loader" out of the XCode package to somewhere else and after that, uploading from the Application Loader worked fine.